# tengo problemas con function coinConvert(usDollar) conversor de dólares a soles peruanos, pesos mexicanos y pesos chilenos

Tags: javascript

Tengo una duda me piden 3 cantidades para convertir 50, 100, 85 y no sé cómo agregarla y tengo una función `coinConvert`.

Me podrían explicar que significa `arr.push, arr, retur arr`, ya hice como 2 formas y no me sale bien. Me dice que no se define, pero mi duda es como poner los tres números a convertir.

El primero que hice solo le agregue `var usDollar= (50,100,85);` y lo volví hacer pero sin `var usDollar`.

Mi código:

```javascript
    module.exports = function coinConvert(usDollar){
    
    var arr=[];
    
    var peruvianSoles = 
    var mexicanPesos=
    var chileanPesos=
    
    arr.push();
    arr.push();
    arr.push();
    return arr;
    };
    
    module.exports= function coinConvert(usDollar){
    
    var arr= [];
    
    var usDollar=(50,100,85);
    var peruvianSoles= usDollar*3.25
    var mexicanPesos= usDollar*18
    var chileanPesos= usDollar*660
    
    arr.push(console.log(peruvianSoles+" soles chilenos"));
    
    arr.push(console.log(mexicanPesos+" pesos mexicanos"));
    
    arr.push(console.log(chileanPesos+" pesos chilenos"));
    return arr;
    };
```

Comment: `funsion` no deberia ser `function`

Comment: Si tienes razón me equivoque en escribirla y todavía así no me sale el resultado

Answer (score 0):

Tu primer problema es que pasas un parametro a la funcion, el cual vuelves a sobreescribir cuando haces `var usDollar=(50,100,85);`

Tu segundo problema es que cuando haces `var usDollar=(50,100,85);` la variable `usDollar` solo se quedara con el valor de 85, el resto lo descarta.

Tu tercer error es a la hora de hacer `push`, estas tratando de agregar a la lista el resultado de `console.log` el cual solo imprimi en consola, pero no retorna nada.

Te dejo este ejemplo para que lo adaptes a tu codigo:

```
function coinConvert(usDollar1, usDollar2, usDollar3){
    var arr= [];

    var peruvianSoles = usDollar1 * 3.25;
    var mexicanPesos = usDollar2 * 18;
    var chileanPesos = usDollar3 * 660;

    arr.push(peruvianSoles + " soles peruanos");

    arr.push(mexicanPesos + " pesos mexicanos");

    arr.push(chileanPesos + " pesos chilenos");

    return arr;
};
```

Si te fijas los tres valores de dolares se pasan como variables, tambien puede ser un array, pero ya tocara modificar la funcion.

La funcion la llamas de la siguiente manera:

```
coinConvert(50, 100, 85);
```

***Actualizando***

Tambien puede hacer la funcion de esta forma:

```
function coinConvert(usDollar){
    var arr= [];

    var peruvianSoles = usDollar * 3.25;
    var mexicanPesos = usDollar * 18;
    var chileanPesos = usDollar * 660;

    arr.push(peruvianSoles + " soles peruanos");

    arr.push(mexicanPesos + " pesos mexicanos");

    arr.push(chileanPesos + " pesos chilenos");

    return arr;
};
```

Y llamas a la funcion asi:

```
coinConvert(50);
coinConvert(100);
coinConvert(85);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por explicarme , ya lo hice como me explicaste pero me sale que usDollar no esta definido. No se si sea por el pontu decimal.

Comment: En el ejemplo, que te coloque usDollar no existe. A ver usDollar que tipo de datos quieres que sea.

Comment: Necesito que las tres sifras 50, 100 ,  85. Que soles peruanos multipliquen 50* 3.25  100* 3.25 y 85*3.25

Comment: Te pregunto: la variable `usDollar` nesecitas pasarla como parametro en la funcion, o simpre tendra los valores de 50, 100 y 85

Comment: ¿El primer `module.exports = function coinConver(...){ ... }` es parte de tu código o solo se 'coló' en tu ejemplo? Además, según yo, debería ser `module.exports.coinConver = function(...){ ... }`.